# Where can I find a beginner's guide to using sysprep for deploying Windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7, deployment, imaging, sysprep

I am new to Windows 7, but want to deploy it in a Netware (read: no Active Directory, no domain, etc.) environment.  I have used Novell Zenworks for imaging and deploying Windows XP in the past, and have never used `sysprep` because it was never necessary.

Now, I find that Zenworks is unable to image Windows 7 at all.  It appears that there is a bunch of hardware-specific information that breaks the image on all machines except the specific machine it was created on.

I have [recently learned](https://superuser.com/questions/68697/what-is-sysprep-how-is-it-useful) what sysprep was, just a few weeks ago.  My question is simple.  Where can I find a step-by-step guide to using `sysprep` to image and deploy Windows 7?

**Edit:** I see that my question has been migrated.  Thanks.  I have read the [guide](http://blog.brianleejackson.com/sysprep-a-windows-7-machine-start-to-finish) that [John T](https://serverfault.com/users/1695/john-t) provided--then I read the 150+ comments.  It seems that this is becoming out of date.  Is there nothing else that sums up how to use `sysprep` to prepare Windows 7 for imaging and deployment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's only one decent guide I've come across so far for Windows 7, and that's [Brian Lee Jackson's "sysprepping" guide](http://theitbros.com/sysprep-a-windows-7-machine-start-to-finish-v2/).